# How to write unit test for controller with a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm learning unit-testing in angularjs and i'm trying to test my authentication controller.

Currently the test is failing with `Expected Function to equal '/dashboard'`. The test does not seem to be getting into `User.login` from what I can tell.

Controller:

```
angular.module('foo').controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $window, $location, User){

 $scope.submit = function () {

      User.login($scope.user,

          function (user) {    // Success
            $window.sessionStorage.token = user.id;
            $scope.message = 'Welcome';
            // Redirect to dashboard
            $location.path('/dashboard');
          },
          function (err) {
            console.log(err);

            // handle login errors
            $scope.message = 'Error: Invalid user or password';
          }
      );
    };
});
```

Test:

```
describe('LoginCtrl', function() {

    beforeEach(module('foo'));

    var scope, ctrl, location, window, user;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $location, $window, User) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    location = $location;
    window = $window;
    user = User;
    ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', {$scope: scope, User: user});
  }));

  it('should redirect upon successful login', function() {
    console.log('before path = '+location.path());
    scope.user = {
      "username": "my_user",
      "password": "my_pass"
    };
    scope.submit();
    console.log('message = '+scope.message);
    console.log('after path = '+location.path());
    console.log(window.sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    expect(location.path).toEqual('/dashboard');
  });

});
```

** EDIT **

User.login code:

```
module.factory(
  "User",
  ['LoopBackResource', 'LoopBackAuth', '$injector', function(Resource, LoopBackAuth, $injector) {
    var R = Resource(
      urlBase + "/users/:id",
      { 'id': '@id' },
      {

      "login": {
          url: urlBase + "/users/login",
          method: "POST",
          interceptor: {
            response: function(response) {
              var accessToken = response.data;
              LoopBackAuth.currentUserId = accessToken.userId;
              LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId = accessToken.id;
              LoopBackAuth.rememberMe = response.config.params.rememberMe !== false;
              LoopBackAuth.save();
              return response.resource;
            }
          }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `User.login` function must be calling the callback method **asynchronously**, so when you call `scope.submit();`, your callback function **is not called yet** => the test fails.

To test this logic, you have to mock the `User.login` function:

```
 it('should redirect upon successful login', function() {
    console.log('before path = '+location.path());
    scope.user = {
      "username": "my_user",
      "password": "my_pass"
    };

    //user here is user = User; in your beforeEach. I avoid pasting too much code.
    //Jasmine 1.3: andCallFake
    //Jasmine 2.0: and.callFake
    spyOn(user, "login").andCallFake(function(userData,successCallback){
         successCallback(userData); //simulate the success case.
    }); //mock your User.login

    scope.submit();
    console.log('message = '+scope.message);
    console.log('after path = '+location.path());
    console.log(window.sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    expect(location.path()).toEqual('/dashboard'); //fix the problem with location.path
 });
```

**Explanation**:

`spyOn(user, "login").andCallFake` replaces the actual function with our fake function.

In this test case, you're testing `should redirect upon successful login`, so the precondition is **the login must be successful**, by mocking the login function, we can ensure this precondition is **always** true in the test.

You could do this similarly to test a case like: `set error message when login failed`, in order to test this, you need to ensure the precondition `login failed` is **always** true in the test:

```
it('should redirect upon successful login', function() {
    console.log('before path = '+location.path());
    scope.user = {
      "username": "my_user",
      "password": "my_pass"
    };

    //user here is user = User; in your beforeEach. I avoid pasting too much code.
    //Jasmine 1.3: andCallFake
    //Jasmine 2.0: and.callFake
    spyOn(user, "login").andCallFake(function(userData,successCallback,errorCallback){
         errorCallback(userData); //simulate the error case.
    }); //mock your User.login

    scope.submit();

    expect(scope.message).toEqual('Error: Invalid user or password'); //verify that the message was set correctly.
 });
```

Comment: @Catfish: you need to provide source code of `User.login` so that we can have further discussion

Comment: Can you please provide a code example? I'm trying to wrap my head around how to unit-test and what to unit-test.

Comment: Awesome it seems to work. I was not aware of spyOn. Can you elaborate more on what is actually going on with the spyOn function? Specifically the `.andCallFake` piece and the callback? How do i know that the success callback is getting called rather than the error callback? How can i write another test that spies on the error callback?

Comment: @Catfish: see my updated answer, let me know if something is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

> Expected Function to equal '/dashboard'

The test runner is telling you it expected a string `'/dashboard'`, but instead got a reference to a function. That's because `location.path` **is** a reference to a function. Try this instead:

```
expect(location.path()).toEqual('/dashboard');
```

Comment: `Expected '' to equal '/dashboard'`

Comment: that means that your current `location.path()` is `''` ... which means that the redirect did **not** happen... time to debug your code. In your test after `scope.submit()` try adding `scope.$apply()`

Comment: That's why I asked this question. I'm not sure if i'm writing the test correctly, or what I should do differently. The endpoint works fine in my app, but in my unit-test i'm not sure how to call it, wait for it to return, and then compare the $location.path to see what the value is.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but I edited my reply to say try `scope.$apply()`... did you do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54303/discussion-between-gil-birman-and-catfish).

Comment: @Catfish: this does not solve the main problem. The code is still an integration test because you're still making `real requests` to server. In order to test, you need to set up the server and the result of the test is unpredictable depending on the server.

Comment: @Catfish: another problem is this test assumes that the logic of `User.login`: the `User.login` checks the input, does some logic, call the callback function passing in a parameter,....